# Why does water run around the rim of sleeves of wet clothes before falling?

Tags: everyday-life

I was washing my pants dry and I noticed something interesting...

> [image]

The water drop lets run do a loop around the edge of the sleeve before falling  on the ground.

What is the physics behind this?

Comment: I have noticed it on electric wires during rainfalls too. I thought it was because of some local curvature on the wire but this animation made me think again.. +1

Answer (score 1):

Water from up the sleeve is pushed downwards by the force of gravity and the surface tension keeps the water initially from falling but when enough water is collected and/or the shape of the edge of the sleeve is sharp/edgy enough it will break surface tension and fall in the form of droplets.